# Anytime I enter value of >= 13 it does not display anything

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
   public class Ozo {
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
     Scanner Henry = new Scanner (System.in);
     System.out.println("Hello Welcome to Algorithm Chemist\nHow may we 
     help you?");
     String name, stress;
     int age;
     System.out.println("Please what is your name?");
     name = Henry.nextLine();
     System.out.println("What is your stress?");
     stress = Henry.nextLine();
     System.out.println("How old are you?");
     age = Henry.nextInt();
     if (age <= 12 && stress == "HeadAce") {
      System.out.println("Take one tablet of Panadol Extra and one 
       tablet of Paracetamol");
     if (age >=13 && stress == "HeadAce") {
      System.out.println("Take two Tablet of Paracetamol and one tablet 
      of Panadol");
     if (age <= 12 && stress == "Malaria") {
      System.out.println("Take one dose of Alabukun or better advise go 
      for herbal medicine");
    if (age >= 13 && stress == "Malaria") {
     System.out.println("Take two dose of Alabukun and one tablet of 
     Postinol");
    System.out.println("Thank you for using our service, we sincerely appreciate your patronage");
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
}
```

I am creating a project in Java. And anytime I enter a value of >= 13 it does not display anything.

Comment: Try to change: `stress = Henry.nextLine();` to: `stress = Henry.nextLine().strip();`

Comment: You may refer to this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: the tests should be changed to `stress.equals("Malaria")`. feel free to refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java for the details

Comment: Spelling: I think you mean "Headache", not "HeadAce".

Comment: If you put this code in an automatic reformatter, you'll see what the problem is - all of those conditions are nested. So, if the first one does not trigger, none of them will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your brackets are incorrect. You'll want to refactor this to use if/else-if structure.

```
if (age <= 12 && stress == "HeadAce") {
    System.out.println("Take one tablet of Panadol Extra and one tablet of Paracetamol");
}else if (age >=13 && stress == "HeadAce") {
    System.out.println("Take two Tablet of Paracetamol and one tablet of Panadol");
}else if (age <= 12 && stress == "Malaria") {
    System.out.println("Take one dose of Alabukun or better advise go for herbal medicine");
}else if (age >= 13 && stress == "Malaria") {
    System.out.println("Take two dose of Alabukun and one tablet of Postinol");
}
```

The problem you have right now is all of your if's are nested. For instance the first two:

```
if (age <= 12 && stress == "HeadAce") {
    System.out.println("Take one tablet of Panadol Extra and one tablet of Paracetamol");
    if (age >=13 && stress == "HeadAce") {
        System.out.println("Take two Tablet of Paracetamol and one tablet of Panadol");
    }
}
```

The only way for the inner `println` will execute is if `age <= 12 && stress == "HeadAce" && age >= 13 && stress == "HeadAce"` and since age cannot be both less than 13 and greater than 12 it will never run that inner `println`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the second condition is nested with your formatting :

```
if (age <= 12 && stress.equals("HeadAce")) { // use equals for string value comparison
    System.out.println("Take one tablet of Panadol Extra and one tablet of Paracetamol");
} // you might want to place these
if (age >=13 && stress.equals("HeadAce")) {
    System.out.println("Take two Tablet of Paracetamol and one tablet of Panadol");
}
if (age <= 12 && stress.equals("Malaria")) {
    System.out.println("Take one dose of Alabukun or better advise go for herbal medicine");
}
if (age >= 13 && stress.equals("Malaria")) {
     System.out.println("Take two dose of Alabukun and one tablet of Postinol");
}
System.out.println("Thank you for using our service, we sincerely appreciate your patronage");
```

And because of that nesting, the inner `if` is not reached. From your implementation, seems like you should be closing the `if` and then using subsequent calls should be made as shared above.